# Which is 100% free VPN for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, vpn

Which is the best virtual private network? With 100% free.

Currently our government has blocked social media like Facebook, Whats App and YouTube. I need to access those web sites. I think if I use some virtual private network, I can access those. Help me to install some virtual private network.

Comment: i am in sri lanka. please help me.

Comment: I have used [VPNGate](https://vpngate.net) and doesn't have to pay anything, they have their fair usage policy though. You might want to check it out.

Comment: @Jim Without the www. in https://vpngate.net it gives me a "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" error, but https://www.vpngate.net works fine (I see askubuntu's auto-formatting is hiding the difference in the two URL's)

Comment: Have a look at https://www.reddit.com/r/VPN/comments/bfzbw9/vpns_working_in_sri_lanka/

Comment: "which is the best virtual private network.??"  that is a question that changes over time so not a good for AU. There are several vpn's for browsers too. Opera even has one built in. So you do not really need one specific for Ubuntu either.

Comment: I can recommend you [NordVPN](https://nordvpn.com/download/) but yes it is not free but it is very rich for features and well polished and easy to work with Linux

Comment: There are some good free VPNs as well but of course some best services if you need support or anything at best that is when you need to pay a little for the service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is mainly related to a VPN *service* (which is unrelated to Ubuntu) rather than a desktop client (on Ubuntu).

Comment: better ask this on [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: @Melebius I voted to Leave Open because there is free software in Ubuntu repositories for this. For more information please read the answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest using

```
sudo apt install proxychains
```

Features:

- Access Internet from behind restrictive firewall
- Source IP masquerade
- SSH tunneling and forwarding
- Dynamic LAN-to-LAN VPN channel
- Servers and daemons friendly (works fine with sendmail MTA)

You will also need to install a Tor relay.

Lastly,

Edit the proxychains.conf file at the bottom and change sock4 to sock5

Answer (score 0):

When it is about Free VPN and Ubuntu, I always go for [OpenVPN](https://www.ovpn.com/en/guides/ubuntu-cli).
Here is [a detailed guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openvpn.html) how to install it from the official documentation of Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

There are quite a few VPNs that are free and compatible with Ubuntu. I personally love Surfshark as recommended in this article on [Free Ubuntu VPNs](https://www.vpnranks.com/free-vpn/ubuntu/). But keep in mind that Surfshark only offers a 30-day money-back guarantee and you will have to claim a refund within this period to get enjoy this VPN free of cost for a whole month.

For a more permanent solution ProtonVPN and Windscribe are your best bet. The former offers unlimited bandwidth, though Windscribe caps data at 10GB/month. Performance-wise, all of these VPNs are pretty good, but Surfshark is a rare service because it has a GUI-based interface for Ubuntu.